# Why does componentWillUnmount() not working?

Tags: react-native

*I want to remove event listener after navigate another screen however componentWillUnmount() not working ?*
*I navigate like this:*

> this.props.navigation.navigate('newScreen')

*after navigate I want to remove listener with componentWillUnmount*

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.handleBackPress,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.warn('removed');
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    return true;
  };
```

Comment: Which navigator are you using?

Comment: react-navigation @Auticcat

Comment: Yes, but is it a Stack/Switch/Drawer/Tab ? And how are they defined=

Comment: oh sorry , I use  Stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using a `StackNavigator`, the previous screen won't unmount if you do a `navigate`.

Take for example 3 screens inside a Stack :

```
Screen1 (initialRoute)

Screen2

Screen3
```

The moment you mount the `StackNavigator`, you'll have a Stack with one element.

Stack: Screen1

Navigating to another screen in a `Stack`, won't unmount the first screen, it will keep it active and push the next screen to the `Stack`.

So, doing. `this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen2")` will leave the Stack looking like:

Stack: Screen1 (unfocused), Screen2(focused).

If you push another screen to the `Stack`, it will keep all screens mounted.

`this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen3")`

Stack: Screen1 (unfocused), Screen2(unfocused), Screen3(focused).

The screens will only unmount (using `navigate`) if you navigate to an already mounted screen.

Doing:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("Screen1")
```

will leave the `Stack` like:

Stack: Screen1

The solution for your problem would be to use the `navigation` HOC `withNavigationFocus`.

withNavigation focus will let you know when the screen is focused or not, and from that know do what you need. Your component would look like:

```
import { withNavigationFocus } from "react-navigation"

...

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.handleBackPress,
    );
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if(prevProps.isFocused !== this.props.isFocused)
      this.props.isFocused === true 
    ? this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    : this.backHandler.remove();

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.warn('removed');
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    return true;
  };

...

export default withNavigationFocus(Component);
```